# How to verify that a webpage exist

Tags: c, http, sockets

I am sending HTTP GET request and receiving data here:

```
ssize_t numBytes = recvfrom(sock, request, 1000, 0,
                   (struct sockaddr *) &myaddr, &fromAddrLen);
    if(numBytes < 0)
        printf("The requested resource does not exist.\n");
    else
        printf("the webpage exist :)\n");
```

I want to check whether the requested page exist or not. But even if a page does not exist, status message is often sent from server (something like "404 not found").
It is still some data, thus I cannot get numBytes<0.

How can I check the status of response to be able to verify the existence of the page?

Comment: I think `recvfrom()` is for UDP. HTTP uses TCP though.

Comment: `recvfrom()` can be used with TCP, though it is not common practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have to read the first line of the response and extract the status code. If it's a 4xx or 5xx code something went wrong (404 = Not Found, 403 = Access Denied).

Comment: But at this point you should probably be using some kind of [HTTP parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser).

Comment: Is the status code in the headers or do you have to extract it from the body of the page?  Some people are getting pretty creative with their 404 pages...

Comment: @Gary It's in the very first line of the response, before the headers.

Comment: thats what i thought. can you give me some indication of the way i supposed to write the code?

Comment: It is always in the headers. Only look at the code though. The first line is always like this: `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` - it might also be `HTTP/1.0` and the string after the code might differ. I saw some french site which actually had a french status message after the code. yuck!

Comment: He sould be doing a HEAD request, is better because the server don't have to process the page and send it, just tell in a error code if the page exist or not.

Comment: @Tei: Generally spoken that's true, but if that fails it's a good idea to retry with GET. I've seen some servers which reject HEAD requests; usually with the appropriate 405 code but some with other status codes.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for numBytes < 0 only allows you to determine whether there is a fatal TCP error, such as connection failed. To find out whether the page exists, you need to implement a part of the HTTP protocol. I recommend you to use a library, such as [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) or [libwww](http://www.w3.org/Library/).

Comment: i m not gonna use libraries. this is an assignment :)

Comment: Then you have to write your own HTTP parser, at least in part, so you should read RFC 2616 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), which defines how HTTP works.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html